# 2D array: creating, initializing, and summing

Tags: java, arrays, sum

So I'm supposed to create a program that creates a 3 x 4 array that looks something like:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

I managed to figure out a way to print that array, but the second part of my directions told me to sum up my totals. And when I compile and run this program, I get the result 42, when it should be 30. My directions also tell me that I need to use nested for loops for creating and intializing AND for summing up the array.

```
public class PartA {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int [][] array = new int [3][4];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
                int k = array[0][j];
                int l = array[1][j];
                array[0][j] = (i+1)+(j);
                array[1][j] = k;
                array[2][j] = l;
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
                sum += array[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the contents of this array is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot the question: I'm assuming I did something wrong with initializing the array. The code for summing the array up is what my teacher gave me to use. So what did I do wrong in initializing the array? Does it have to do with int k,l?

Comment: Do you think you are modifying the values of same array every now and then and printing just at some point in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum code is perfectly fine. But issue is with the way you initialize the array. See your code here:

```
 int k = array[0][j];
 int l = array[1][j];
 array[0][j] = (i+1)+(j);
 array[1][j] = k;
 array[2][j] = l;
```

See that when `i=0` and `j = 0`, you are modifying value of `array[0][0]` as 1
While for `i =1`, `j =0`, you are again modifying the value of `array[0][0]` as 2 and so on.

So initialize your array like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        array[i][j] = j + 1;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are assigning all arrays again and again. After first for loop if you print your array it will look like.

```
3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
```

So Replace below code

```
array[0][j] = (i+1)+(j);
array[1][j] = k;
array[2][j] = l;
```

With

```
array[i][j] = j+1;
```